# Python Large Functions Many Variables (Refactoring)

Tags: python

I have a large function in my script that contains the bulk of the logic of my program.

At one point, it used to span ~100 lines which I then tried to refactor into multiple smaller functions. However, I had many local variables that were eventually being modified in the smaller functions, and I needed some way to keep track of them in the scope of the larger function.

For instance, it looked like

```
def large_func():
 x = 5
 ... 100 lines ...
```

to

```
def large_func():
   x = 6
   small_func_that_will_increment_x()
   small_func()
   ....
```

What is a pythonic way to handle this?

The two approaches I can think of are:

1) global variables --- will probably get messy as I have many variables
2) using a dict to keep track of them like

```
tracker = {
'field1' : 5
'field2' : 4
}
```

and make modifications on the dict instead.

Is there a different way to do this that I might have overlooked?

Comment: Do each of the smaller functions only modify one variable at a time?

Comment: If the local variables all conceptually fit together into some kind of thing worth talking about, create a class. (Even if they don't, you can create a class just to use as a namespace… but in that case, a dict is more likely to be what you want.)

Comment: maybe submit your long function (or part of it) to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ -- you may get more concrete advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without more information, it's hard to know whether this is appropriate or not, but…

An object is a namespace. In particular, you can turn each of those local variables into attributes on an object. For example:

```
class LargeThing(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 6
    def large_func(self):
        self.small_func_that_will_increment_x()
        self.small_func()
        # ...
    def small_func_that_will_increment_x(self):
        self.x += 1
```

Whether the `self.x = 6` belongs in `__init__` or at the start of `large_func`, or whether this is even a good idea, depends on what all those variables actually mean, and how they fit together.

Answer (score 3):

Closures will work here:

```
def large_func()
   x = 6

   def func_that_uses_x():
       print x

   def func_that_modifies_x():
       nonlocal x  # python3 only
       x += 1

   func_that_uses_x()
   func_that_modifies_x()
```

Answer (score 3):

Another tip - make use of Python's ability to return multiple values. If you have a function that modifies two variables, do something like this:

```
def modifies_two_vars(a, b, c, d):
    return a+b, c+d

x, y = modifies_two_vars(x, y, z, w)
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative could be:

```
def small_func_that_will_return_new_x(old_x):
  return old_x + 1

def large_func():
  x = small_func_that_will_return_new_x(6)
```

instead of:

```
def large_func():
   x = 6
   small_func_that_will_increment_x()
```

Answer (score 0):

Object composition. Create small objects that hold state, and then feed them as initializers an object that manages them. See [Global State and Singletons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI&index=2&list=PL693EFD059797C21E)

"Build the door knob, which you use to build the door, which you use to construct the house. Not the other way around"